# Easily parallelize R nested for loop with foreach?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, parallel-processing, nested

I have this triple loop with the output all being written to the same array, asc.a.out. I was wondering if there is a simple way to parallelize this, I tried foreach (now commented out), but the output array was empty. Is there a simple way to speed up constructs like this, I remember in MATLAB loops could simply be converted to parallel loops without any major code changes, much like openmp. The reason my data is within this structure is because it's spatial data with a time series at each location.

edit:
I have added a simple example at the end.

```
asc.a     = array(55,dim=c(120,180,2190)) # filled with nonsense data as an example.
asc.a.out = array(NaN,dim=c(120,180,426))

for (i in 1:120) {
#foreach (i = 1:120) %dopar% {
for (j in 1:180) {

  yy = seq(1:2190)

  asc.a.b = rbind(asc.a[i,j,1:365],asc.a[i,j,366:730],asc.a[i,j,731:1095],asc.a[i,j,1096:1460],asc.a[i,j,1461:1825],asc.a[i,j,1826:2190])
  asc.a.b = cbind(asc.a.b[,335:365],asc.a.b,asc.a.b[,1:30])

  asc.a.c = c(asc.a[i,j,1:365],asc.a[i,j,366:730],asc.a[i,j,731:1095],asc.a[i,j,1096:1460],asc.a[i,j,1461:1825],asc.a[i,j,1826:2190])

  check = asc.a.c
  check = sort(asc.a.c,decreasing = T)
  if (sum(!is.na(check[1:365])) < 100) next

  model <- rlm(asc.a.c ~ poly(yy,25))
  predicted.intervals <- predict(model,data.frame(x=yy),interval='confidence',level=0.99)

  asc.a.c.tmp = asc.a.c - predicted.intervals[,1]

  sd = sd(asc.a.c.tmp,na.rm=T)
  med = median(asc.a.c.tmp,na.rm=T)
  q25 = quantile(asc.a.c.tmp,na.rm=T)
  asc.a.c.tmp[asc.a.c.tmp < (0-sd)] = NaN
  asc.a.c.tmp[asc.a.c.tmp > (0+sd)] = NaN

  asc.clim = asc.a.c.tmp + predicted.intervals[,1]
  asc.a.d = rbind(asc.clim[1:365],asc.clim[366:730],asc.clim[731:1095],asc.clim[1096:1460],asc.clim[1461:1825],asc.clim[1826:2190])
  asc.a.d = cbind(asc.a.d[,335:365],asc.a.d,asc.a.d[,1:30])

  for (k in 16:411) {

    tmp1 = asc.a.b[,((k-15):(k+15))]
    tmp = quantile(asc.a.d[,((k-15):(k+15))],na.rm=T)

    tmp1[tmp1 < tmp[2]] = NaN
    tmp1[tmp1 > tmp[4]] = NaN

    asc.a.out[i,j,k] = mean(tmp1,na.rm=T)
  }
}
print(i)
}
```

edit:
smaller example with same code structure as above.

```
asc.a     = array(55,dim=c(120,180,426)) 
asc.a.out = array(NaN,dim=c(120,180,426))

for (i in 1:120) {
#foreach (i = 1:120) %dopar% {
 for (j in 1:180) {

 tmp = asc.a[i,j,]

  for (k in 16:411) {
   tmp1 = tmp[((k-15):(k+15))]
   asc.a.out[i,j,k] = mean(tmp1,na.rm=T)
  }
 }
print(i)
}
```

Comment: Debugging code is harder than finding a newer solution. Please provide a sample of data and expected output.

Comment: Check out: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

Comment: With foreach you need to return the data at the end of the "loop". The foreach can combine it using the function given by foreach(,,,. combine='FUNCTION'), e.g., foreach(...,combine='rbind').

Comment: [Some tuto with foreach](https://privefl.github.io/blog/a-guide-to-parallelism-in-r/)